# Managed to make Tic-Tac-Toe as someone who is new to coding

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to build up a toolset of best practices, so as this is my first complete program (if you can call it that) writen in c++, I know there's definitely better ways of doing things

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

void buildGrid(char arr[]) {
    string line = "---|---|---\n";

    cout << " " << arr[0] << " | " << arr[1] << " | " << arr[2] << "\n" << line;
    cout << " " << arr[3] << " | " << arr[4] << " | " << arr[5] << "\n" << line;
    cout << " " << arr[6] << " | " << arr[7] << " | " << arr[8] << "\n";
}

bool checkLines(char a, char arr[9]) {
    if (arr[0] == a && arr[1] == a && arr[2] == a) {
        return true;
        /*
         x | x | x 
        ---|---|---
         3 | 4 | 5 
        ---|---|---
         6 | 7 | 8 
        */

    } else if (arr[3] == a && arr[4] == a && arr[5] == a) {
        return true;
        /*
         0 | 1 | 2 
        ---|---|---
         x | x | x 
        ---|---|---
         6 | 7 | 8 
        */

    } else if (arr[6] == a && arr[7] == a && arr[8] == a) {
        return true;
        /*
         0 | 1 | 2 
        ---|---|---
         3 | 4 | 5 
        ---|---|---
         x | x | x 
        */

    } else if (arr[0] == a && arr[3] == a && arr[6] == a) {
        return true;
        /*
         x | 1 | 2 
        ---|---|---
         x | 4 | 5 
        ---|---|---
         x | 7 | 8 
        */

    } else if (arr[1] == a && arr[4] == a && arr[7] == a) {
        return true;
        /*
         0 | x | 2 
        ---|---|---
         3 | x | 5 
        ---|---|---
         6 | x | 8 
        */

    } else if (arr[2] == a && arr[5] == a && arr[8] == a) {
        return true;
        /*
         0 | 1 | x 
        ---|---|---
         3 | 4 | x 
        ---|---|---
         6 | 7 | x 
        */

    } else if (arr[0] == a && arr[4] == a && arr[8] == a) {
        return true;
        /*
         x | 1 | 2 
        ---|---|---
         3 | x | 5 
        ---|---|---
         6 | 7 | x 
        */

    } else if (arr[2] == a && arr[4] == a && arr[6] == a) {
        return true;
        /*
         0 | 1 | x 
        ---|---|---
         3 | x | 5 
        ---|---|---
         x | 7 | 8 
        */

    }
    return false;
}

char whoUp(char a, char b, char c) {
    if (c == a) {
        c = b;
    } else if (c == b) {
        c = a;
    }     
    return c;
}

int main() {
    int input;
    int spacesLeft = 9;
    char gridPos[9] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    char first;
    char second;
    char c;

    cout << "who goes first?(a-z): ";
    cin >> first;
    do {
        c = cin.get();
    } while (c != '\n');

    cout << "who goes second?(a-z): ";
    cin >> second;
    do {
        c = cin.get();
    } while (c != '\n');

    char up = first;

    cout << "\nspaces left: " << spacesLeft << endl;

    buildGrid(gridPos);

    cout << up << ", choose a space(1-9): ";
    while (!(cin >> input).fail()) {
        input -= 1;
        if (input < 0 || input > 8) {
            cout << "invalid space\n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        } else if (gridPos[input] == first || gridPos[input] == second) {
            cout << "space already taken\n";
            cout << "\nspaces left: " << spacesLeft << endl;
            cin.clear();cin.ignore (numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        } else {
            spacesLeft--;
            gridPos[input] = up;
            bool check = checkLines(up, gridPos);

            if (check == true) {
                cout << "the winner is: " << up << endl;
                break;
            } else if (check == false) {
                cout << "\nspaces left: " << spacesLeft << endl;
                up = whoUp(first, second, up);
            }
        }

        buildGrid(gridPos);

        if (spacesLeft == 0) {
            cout << "no more spaces left\n";
            break;
        }

        cout << up << ", choose a space(1-9): ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please accept any answer, this questino is 1 month old

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### General Observations

For someone who is new to coding you did pretty well, there are no global variables and that is excellent. There are functions, there could be more but still excellent. I for one believe you are following a best practice by embedding the code in an if statement within braces (`{` and `}`), it makes the code much easier to maintain.

While I understand why you put the comments in that you did, the code would be more readable without them. Comments need to be maintained as well as code does.

### Avoid `using namespace std;`

If you are coding professionally you probably should get out of the habit of using the `using namespace std;` statement. The code will more clearly define where `cout` and other identifiers are coming from (`std::cin`, `std::cout`). As you start using namespaces in your code it is better to identify where each function comes from because there may be function name collisions from different namespaces. The identifier`cout` you may override within your own classes, and you may override the operator `<<` in your own classes as well. This [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) discusses this in more detail.

### DRY Code

There is a programming principle called the [Don't Repeat Yourself Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) sometimes referred to as DRY code. If you find yourself repeating the same code multiple times it is better to encapsulate it in a function. If it is possible to loop through the code that can reduce repetition as well.

By removing the comments we can see that there is repetition in the following function:

```
bool checkLines(char a, char arr[9]) {
    if (arr[0] == a && arr[1] == a && arr[2] == a) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (arr[3] == a && arr[4] == a && arr[5] == a) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (arr[6] == a && arr[7] == a && arr[8] == a) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (arr[0] == a && arr[3] == a && arr[6] == a) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (arr[1] == a && arr[4] == a && arr[7] == a) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (arr[2] == a && arr[5] == a && arr[8] == a) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (arr[0] == a && arr[4] == a && arr[8] == a) {
        return true;

    }
    else if (arr[2] == a && arr[4] == a && arr[6] == a) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

The repetion can be reduced by having 2 additional functions, `checkRow(size_t firstColumnInRow)` and `checkColumn(size_t firstRowInColumn)`. There isn't enough diagonal repetiton to create a third function.

```
bool checkRow(char user, char arr[], size_t firstColumnInRow)
{
    if (arr[firstColumnInRow] == user && arr[firstColumnInRow + 1] == user && arr[firstColumnInRow + 2] == user) {
        return true;
    }
}

bool checkColumn(char user, char arr[], size_t firstRowInColumn)
{
    if (arr[firstRowInColumn] == user && arr[firstRowInColumn + 2] == user && arr[firstRowInColumn + 6] == user) {
        return true;
    }
}

bool checkLines(char a, char arr[9]) {
    size_t rowStarts[] = {0, 3, 6};
    for (size_t row = 0; row < sizeof(rowStarts) / sizeof(*rowStarts); row++)
    {
        if (checkRow(a, arr, rowStarts[row])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    size_t columnStarts[] = {0, 1, 2};
    for (size_t column = 0; column < 3; column++)
    {
        if (checkColumn(a, arr, columnStarts[column])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (arr[0] == a && arr[4] == a && arr[8] == a) {
        return true;

    }
    else if (arr[2] == a && arr[4] == a && arr[6] == a) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

Using the DRY principle generally results in less code, it didn't happen this time because the sample size is so small. There are variations on this code that would result in less code, such as having `checkRow(size_t firstColumnInRow)` be `checkRows(char user, char arr[], size_t rowStarts[])` and move the loop into the function.

### Always Check User Input

What a user enters may not be the correct type for the receiving variable, always check user input to see that it is correct, an example in this program is that when entering a box id number the user could use a character rather than a number (I did, the program just sat there).

Answer (score 1):

Due to the simplicity, there isn't much you need to change, it's good but just a few suggestions

### Don't use `using namespace std;`

It is considered bad practice to have this in your program
Refer to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice/#:%7E:text=The%20statement%20using%20namespace%20std%20is%20generally%20considered%20bad%20practice.&text=In%20the%20worst%20case%2C%20the,to%20resolve%20identifier%20name%20conflicts.) link to understand why it is a bad practice and why you should avoid it

### Display the board after the game is over

After a player as won, you shall display the board again with using `buildGrid(gridPos);` and then break, so you can see the end position of the game

### Prefer using "\n" over `std::endl`

Both `endl` and `"\n"` serve the same purpose in C++ – they insert a new line. However, the key difference between them is that `endl` causes flushing of the output buffer every time it is called, whereas `"\n"` does not.

While the difference is not obvious in smaller programs, endl performs significantly worse than \n because of the constant flushing of the output buffer.

source: [What is the difference between \n and endl?](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-difference-between-endl-and-n-in-cpp)

### Clear the terminal after every turn

After the player makes a move, you can clear the whole terminal and then display the usual stuff rather than threading the whole thing.

If you are on windows

```
system("CLS");
```

### Formate your code to make it look more legible

White spaces don't mean anything to the compiler, it is for the programmers' legibility.
You can use something like [this online c++ code formatter](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_c_formatter.htm) to make your code look better in 2-3 clicks